# Introduction to filtering - Kalman filtering

Tags: kalman-filter, filter

I would like to make a preamble and then introducing the Kalman filter in a work I am writing. In your opinion which are the topics I have to cite?

Do you think I should cite Kolmogorov and Wiener filtering?
Do you have good readings to suggest?